# How to Start a New Chapter on Any Page and Avoid Blank Pages

Tags: chapters, blank-page

If you run the code for the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\chapter*{1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter*{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{3}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

you should see that a blank page is generated on page 4.

QUESTION: (i) How may the above code be modified so that a new chapter always begins on the page following the end of the previous chapter? (ii) Ignoring (i), is there a command that I could use that would eliminate the blank page on pg. 4 of the output of the MWE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `openany` will solve the issue:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you. It does indeed.

Comment: Many many many compliments for your reputation of 10k. My always best regards.

Comment: Great pleasure to receive such kind words from one of Great in `TeX&LaTeX`...Really didn't expect and it's one of my ever remembering compliment....Thanks a lot....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Ahahahahah. I love the surprises. :-)